# Angular UI Router state.go parameters not available in stateChangeStart

Tags: angular-ui-router

I'm using Angular UI Router and I need to send a parameter with the state.go method. Like this:

```
$state.go('myState', { redirect : true });
```

I also need to check that parameter in the event stateChangeStart. Like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    //redirect parameter is not available here.
    //should be in toParams right?
}
```

Edit: here's my statedefinition:

```
    $stateProvider.state('customer.search', {
        url: '/search',
        views: {
            "right-flyover@": {
                templateUrl: 'customer/search/search.tpl.html',
                controller: 'CustomerSearchCtrl'
            }
        },
        data: {
            pageTitle: 'Sök användare',
            hidden: true
        }
    });
```

Comment: It would be there if this state does expect it. Could you show your state def please?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `ui-router` will pass parameters which were defined for a *state hierarchy* - we are navigating to. Please check:

[URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters) *(cite:)*

Often, URLs have dynamic parts to them which are called parameters. There are several options for specifying parameters. A basic parameter looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /contacts/42
            expect($stateParams).toBe({contactId: 42});
        }
    })
```

So, if you want to work with *param* `redirect`, your state should look like this:

```
$stateProvider.state('customer.search', {
    url: '/search/:redirect',
    ...        
});
```

then we can use:

```
$state.go('customer.search', { redirect : true });
```

and that would be part of `$statePrams`

But maybe you try to use sent options, not parameters:

- [$state.go(to [, toParams] [, options])](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) *(cite:)*

#### options

> Object - If Object is passed, object is an options hash. The following options are supported:

- location Boolean or "replace" (default true), If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. If string "replace", will update url and also replace last history record.
- inherit Boolean (default true), If true will inherit url parameters from current url.
- relative stateObject (default $state.$current), When transitioning with relative path (e.g '^'), defines which state to be relative from.
- notify Boolean (default true), If true will broadcast $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events.
- reload v0.2.5 Boolean (default false), If true will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search params.

And that would be then the third param *(reload instead of redirect)*:

```
$state.go('myState', null, { reload: true });
```

Comment: I see, params are not what I want. But neither is options. The goal here is to supply the state change with some meta information, i.e "this state change is a redirect". Sort of like http header information.

Comment: I know what you are asking for. But sadly - I am explaining to you what you can get ;) that's what we do have with ui-router, out of the box... but you still can broadcast and listen your own events... that would mostlikely be the way to go... Does it help anyhow?

Answer (score 1):

I recently solved the problem by using cache attribute is stateProvider and set it to false
like

```
 .state('home.stats', {
        cache: false,
        url:'/stats',
        templateUrl: 'views/stats.html',
        controller: 'StatsCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'stats'
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

$state.go actually returns a promise, so you can do something like:

```
$state.go('myState').then(() => { 
  if (redirect) {
    // do something
  }
});
```

I realize this isn't a generalized solution to the problem which is what I was looking for as well, but it allowed me to get the job done.  You could easily wrap this in a method on the $state object if you need to reuse the logic repeatedly.